# Install 64 bit CentOS on Vbox installed on 32 bit Windows 7 with 64 bit intel 3rd gen core i5 processor

Tags: linux, windows, centos, 64-bit, virtualbox

I want to install 64 bit CentOS6 on the following configuration.

- Processor: 3rd Generation Intel Core i5 (64 bit)
- Operating System: Windows 7 (32 bit)
- Virtual Machine software: Oracle Vbox

When I try to install x86_64 version of CentOS, I get an error 'i686 processor found. could not install x86_64 on this box'.

I checked my processor bit through the software from Intel to find what is processor's bit size which returns 64.

Am I going wrong anywhere? What is the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called Intel Virtualization Technology, and AMD V, for those respective boards, so it needs to be enabled.

Where can you enable it from? It's in the BIOS; press ‘esc’ when you see the Vendor logo and you will reach the pre boot screen from where you can choose the bios, browse around, find Virtualization Technology and Enable it.

Comment: Alok, that was really helpful. However, I see from the BIOS settings that my system is already VT enabled!